# Puzzles and exercises to improve mathematical intelligence and spatial thinking

Tags: recreational-mathematics, self-learning, problem-solving, puzzle

In your childhood or adolescence, or maybe as an adult, have there been types of exercises or puzzles that you think have improved your mathematical intelligence and in particular the spatial thinking?
If yes, which ones?

Comment: I recently discovered https://twitter.com/BongardDaily

Comment: Very nice, thanks for your contribute :) ( I have little reputation points for being able to vote)